# Launch Sublime Text from CLI, paste text from stdin and Pretty Print JSON

Tags: json, bash, sublimetext3, sublimetext, pretty-print

From OS X 10.11.3 Terminal (bash shell), I want to open a JSON string in Sublime Text 3 and use the [Pretty JSON](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Pretty%20JSON) package to "Pretty Print" the JSON string to a better readable format.

According to [Sublime Text 3 documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html), it should be possible to specify commands from the CLI using the --command parameter.

The following command manages to open the JSON string in Sublime Text 3. It fails to Pretty Print the JSON string.

```
echo "{ "menu": { "id": "file", "value": "File" }}" | subl --command jq_pretty_json -
```

Does anybody know how I can apply this Pretty Print command from the OS X command line? When calling the Pretty JSON from the Sublime Text 3 UI, it works without problems.

Comment: Have you tried just using the `pretty_json` command instead of `jq_pretty_json`?

Comment: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/running-an-applicationcommand-via-subl/18434

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command manages to do what I want:

```
echo '{ "menu": { "id": "file", "value": "File" }}' | subl - & sleep 1; subl --command pretty_json
```

Comment: This is great thanks! This `(&>/dev/null subl & sleep 1)` will suppress the background job output!

Answer (score 0):

You can install [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) via [homebrew](http://brew.sh/), and then do:

```
$ echo '{ "menu": { "id": "file", "value": "File" }}' | jq .
{
  "menu": {
    "value": "File",
    "id": "file"
  }
}
```

You have to be careful of your quoting: since you're using double quotes, none of the "interior" quotes will appear in the output of the echo command.